# SQL - is it possible to do this in single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I've got a problem with my sql query (SQL Server)
I've got two tables - persons and accounts
persons have fields - id,account_id, person_type(can by A,B,C,D
accounts have fields - id, account_type(which is null now, can by X or Y)

there are 2000 accounts, but persons table has 3500 records. For example person table can hold 3 records with the same account_id, but different person_type
Here is what I want: 
Based on person table update (in one query) accounts table - this seems easy at that point. if person type is A,B,C put X into account type, if D put Y. But if persons table holds person with B and different person with D and the same accont_id I want to put Y in the accounts and i don't know how to perform it...

Now, I've got a ssis for each loop which is iterating every account_id and checking type but it's very inefficient and takes about 80% of my whole process.

Hope that someone will undersand what I described above :) Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected results to better clarify your question?

Comment: Sounds like a simple JOIN would do what you want, but more information about tables and exepected is needed to give a answer. Maybe post the SSIS.

Comment: And perhaps a CASE for the if/then/else part.

Comment: problem solved by the guy below, so I won't post sample data :) The key element here was the with clause - I didn't know it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below.  You need to group the person records on account_id, and make "Y" override "X" in the case where any person had person_type = "D."  You can do that with a CTE, then join it to accounts table to perform the update.

```
;WITH AccountTypes AS (
    SELECT  account_id
            , MAX(CASE WHEN person_type = 'D' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'X' END) AS account_type
    FROM    persons
    GROUP BY account_id
)
UPDATE  a
SET     a.account_type = at.account_type
FROM    accounts a
        JOIN AccountTypes at ON a.account_id = at.account_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single query, you'll need an update based on a select statment. I've found the MERGE statement to be the best (only?) way to do this. For your if-statement, you can use CASE:

```
MERGE INTO accounts
USING
(
    SELECT accounts.id,
           CASE WHEN person_type in ('A', 'B', 'C')
                THEN 'X'
                WHEN person_type = 'D'
                THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'Z' -- Included as example of the ELSE statement
           END AS account_type
    FROM accounts
    JOIN persons on accounts.id = persons.account_id
) updateTable ON accounts.id = updateTable.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    SET accounts.account_type = updateTable.accountType
```

This is assuming you are using/want to use queries/stored procedures.